# Fetching HTML and changing document body

Tags: javascript, html

Please, do not mark this as a duplicate. I tried everything I could, and this isn't working. I have experience in Javascript. It isn't my first time using it

Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>JUST_LOAD_ALREADY</title>
    <!-- <script defer src="/index.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    PLEASSDETY FGUIRWFVUI
    <script>
      function loadContent() {
        fetch("/content.html")
          .then((res) => res.text())
          .then((text) => (document.body.innerHTML = text));
      }
      loadContent()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

content.html:

```html
<h1>Content page</h1>
```

**Expected page content inside body after everything loads**:
`<h1>Content</h1>`

**Actual page content inside body**:
`PLEAS`

Its neither my frustration text nor `content.html`'s content. This is killing me please help tell me why this is happening. These are the only two files I have + a package.json for running sirv

Comment: The script is inside the body. Maybe you "kill yourself"? Not tested/proof, just an idea.

Comment: Once the script is loaded into the memory, it shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: You must be getting "URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request"  please check on console..

Comment: If you load this page from file:// protocol you will have CORS errors in the console. Also possible: 404 in the network tab

Comment: No, there aren't any errors in the console (exept a 404 for the favicon), since this isn't a CORS request

Comment: There isn't a 404 in the network tab, but there also isn't a request for content.html. It also says ```266 B / 590 B transferred``` at the bottom, I'm not sure what 590 bytes means

Comment: What is the protocol of your loading page

Comment: Going off of @MarkusZeller's comment, I added a div and changed its inner HTML, and now everything works like it should. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Glad that it is working , but with plain vanila JS and HTML page without server hosting it will not work due to CORS , As asked by @mplungjan which protocol / server are you using for this ?

Comment: Could you provide more info about your stack, namely what your network log shows on response body, alternatively try to place some console.log call into your script? I don't believe what you described could happen in any reasonable client if it received whole document correctly; only scenario exhibiting this is incomplete network transfer or corrupted cache of your index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a div with an id and changing its `innerHTML` seems to work, could be "killing yourself" due to having the script inside the body like @MarkusZeller said. The code below worked:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>JUST_LOAD</title>
    <!-- <script defer src="/index.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    PLEASSDETY FGUIRWFVUI
    <main id="content"></main>
    <script>
      function loadContent() {
        fetch("/content.html")
          .then((res) => res.text())
          .then((text) => (document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text));
      }
      loadContent();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively put this in the head

```
window.addEventListener("load",() => { 
  fetch("/content.html")
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => document.body.innerHTML = text);
})
```